# I am not able to create a server in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Every time I try to create a server in pgAdmin, I get an error like "Instance '<0x108cfada0>' is not persisted"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOwDy.png)

I've tried several times to shutdown down my computer but the error is persistent

Comment: I’m not familiar with pgAdmin, but you could use a work around: use a different tool. For example psql, DataGrip, Navicat, DBeaver or something else.